# React Native How to align Center with Native Base Component

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm using native base for my react native project , i try to put all the child of content to align center but it didn't work. Can anyone show me how to do it with native base component ?here is my result

```
<Container  > 

        <Content  contentContainerStyle = { {display : 'flex',backgroundColor:'black', alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',flex:1} } >

        <Item >
          <Input placeholderTextColor = 'white'   placeholder = 'Số điện thoại di động'/> 
        </Item>
         <Item>
         <Input placeholderTextColor = 'white'  placeholder = 'Mật khẩu'/> 
       </Item>
       <Button bordered light >
        <Text style = { {color:'white'} } >Đăng nhập</Text>
      </Button>
      <Grid>
        <Col ><Label  style = { {color:'white'} } >Bạn chưa có tài khoản?</Label></Col>
        <Col ><Label  style = { {color:'white'} }>ĐĂNG KÝ</Label></Col>
      </Grid>
       </Content>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who had same problem, just use `<Content>` props `centerContent={true}` **or** wrap all children in your `<Content>` in a `<View>`.

In this case,

```
<Content
  contentContainerStyle={{
     backgroundColor: "black",
     justifyContent: "center",
     flex: 1
  }}
>
  <View>
     <Item>
        <Input placeholderTextColor="white" placeholder="Số điện thoại di động" />
     </Item>
     <Item>
        <Input placeholderTextColor="white" placeholder="Mật khẩu" />
     </Item>
     <Button bordered light>
         <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Đăng nhập</Text>
     </Button>
     <Grid>
         <Col>
             <Label style={{ color: "white" }}>Bạn chưa có tài khoản?</Label>
         </Col>
         <Col>
             <Label style={{ color: "white" }}>ĐĂNG KÝ</Label>
         </Col>
     </Grid>
  </View>
</Content>
```